# Plot.ly API adding Title

Tags: python, api, pie-chart

I'm using the `Plot.ly API` for the first time and I am trying to visualize the below data for a pie chart. I can't figure out how to generate a title for the pie chart. I thought that `filename='Events by Categories'` would generate the title. Any help would be great, I would like the title to say "Events by Categories". Thanks!

```
def plot_events_by_categories(category_events):
    labels = []
    values = []
    for each in category_events:
        labels.append(each)
        value = category_events[each]
        values.append(len(value))

    trace = go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)
    py.plot([trace], filename='Events by Categories')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
layout = Layout(
    title='Events by Categories.',
)
```

You need to add a title attribute to in your layout and then execute your code.
Please go through the documentation for more info.[Plot.ly Pie Chart](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/)